# Properly escaping a doctype declaration string in Perl search

Tags: string, perl, escaping, find, operators

Using Perl find I cannot successfully escape a DOCTYPE declaration in search string. Here is an example of a string that I am searching for;

```
find . -type f|xargs -d "\n" perl -pi -e 's/ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1\.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www\.w3\.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional\.dtd">//g'
```

to replace the doctype declaration with nothing. Please if someone can properly escape this string so that a perl find can find any string would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why the `/g`, though? I've not some across many HTML documents that had multiple doctypes.

Comment: I think the g is for global so that it will replace more than one instance in a file if found.

Comment: That was my point. The doctype is at the top of an HTML document, only once. Why try to replace it multiple times if there only is one instance of it?

Comment: Oh I see, I was thought it was a general question. This question also is not for specific code but for any string that is comprised of code, and how to escape from the actual code and search only for the string of code. Also, many times searching for code for bulk editing will also include multi-lines which will also require different commands for searching. I am just such a newbie with this command line perl stuff. Thank-you tho for sharing your knowlege!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other delimiters besides `/` in Perl. Try this:

```
s{<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1\.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www\.w3\.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional\.dtd">}{}g
```

Since the slash is no longer delimiting the regex, it is safe to use.

Comment: Actually this worked perfectly for this piece of code, but when I tried this again searching for 's{include('titles.php')}{replacement}g' it will not find this piece of php code within any of the files. Why is this? I tried escaping the brackets, quotes, periods, still nothing works?

Comment: @user1822148 that might be related to the rest of your command. I think in php you can also use `"` instead of `'`. Have you tried this? `s/include(\s*['"]titles\.php['"]\s*)/replacement/g`

Comment: I tried what you posted and it was returned with a bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: @user1822148 I forgot two things: the `(` have to be escaped, and since the `'` are the delimiter for `perl -e`, you need to to escape thoe, too.

Answer (score 4):

As another person suggested, the various `'/'` characters in your regex would need to be escaped with a `'\'` because Perl would read them as ending the `s///;` prematurely otherwise, causing some errors.  You always have to watch out for special characters when dealing with these, as I see you have done with the various periods.

```
's/ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1\.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www\.w3\.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional\.dtd">//g'
```

You can change your delimiters in a `s///;` to something else, such as 
`s###` or `s{}{}` to help allieviate the problem, and I generally recommend doing so if you are working with HTML.

Even so, I would say try to simplify the regex as much as practical for the application.  Because HTML like this can be so nasty to work with, try using a non-greedy match anything sort of regex, but using the `<` and `>` to capture specific tags.  For example, you might use a regex such as this...

`s{<!DOCTYPE .*?>}{}s`

and somewhat explaind format...

```
s{
    <!DOCTYPE   # opening doctype tag
    \s          # one whitepsace
    .*?         # anything (even newlines because of /s flag) non-greedily
     >          # until the first closing greater than 
}{}xs;          # x is ignore whitespace, s is have '.' match anything (even \n)
```

This example uses the `/x` flag to comment it out and explain everything, but if you are doing this on the command line this woudl not be necessary.

I cannot speak as to the rest of the portion of your question as I'm not that familiar with shell commands, only to the regex portion.

Answer (score 0):

If the `DOCTYPE` is on one line, it's better written like this :

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/DOCTYPE/d' {} +
```

or in `perl` :

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i -ne 'print unless /DOCTYPE/' {} +
```

to avoid keeping a blank line.

**NOTE**

- `-i` switch modify the file. Remove it for tests purposes

Answer (score 0):

While the alternate delimiters has already been covered (e.g. `s###`), I would add using `\Q` and `\E` to remove the other escaping needs:

```
s#\Q<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\E##g'
```

Comment: I also tried this for searching .php files for pieces of code such as searching for include('file.php')  but perl find cannot find any strings such as this? Probably something simple, but I cannot search and replace using perl while searching for such php code.